# Angular select box with value differ from option text

Tags: angularjs

I created an angular select box like this:

```
<select ng-model="BC.aOptions_aBadge" ng-options="aOptName for aOptName in {0:'NONE', 1:'Top Left', 2:'Top Right', 3:'Bottom Left', 4:'Bottom Right'}" />
```

This makes the html be:

```
<select xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" ng-model="BC.aOptions_aBadge" ng-options="aOptName for aOptName in {0:'NONE', 1:'Top Left', 2:'Top Right', 3:'Bottom Left', 4:'Bottom Right'}" class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched">
    <option value="string:NONE" label="NONE" selected="selected">NONE</option>
    <option value="string:Top Left" label="Top Left">Top Left</option>
    <option value="string:Top Right" label="Top Right">Top Right</option>
    <option value="string:Bottom Left" label="Bottom Left">Bottom Left</option>
    <option value="string:Bottom Right" label="Bottom Right">Bottom Right</option>
</select>
```

However I want the value of the option to be the key, so it should be 0, 1, 2, 3, 4. While keeping the strings intact, is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [object syntax](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions#usage) (***`select as label for (key , value) in object`***), i.e

```
  ng-options="key as aOptName for (key, aOptName) in {0:'NONE', 1:'Top Left', 2:'Top Right', 3:'Bottom Left', 4:'Bottom Right'}"
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>

  <select ng-model="BC.aOptions_aBadge" ng-options="key as aOptName for (key, aOptName) in {0:'NONE', 1:'Top Left', 2:'Top Right', 3:'Bottom Left', 4:'Bottom Right'}"></select>
  {{BC.aOptions_aBadge}}
</div>
```

Comment: Wow fantastic thank you! What if I had an array of `['0', '1', '2']` and wanted the value to be same and not `string:0`, `string:1` etc?

Comment: @Noitidart What do you mean by array, you mean array of strings bound to the ng-options, why would `string:x` matter for you as long as you only look at the ng-model?

Comment: Ah nevermind sorry, i was just confused because in the html it shows `'string:VAL HERE'`, i think its ok, thanks so much!

Comment: @Noitidart Technically if you care only about what is rendered you could use `track by key` but then you cannot combine it with `select as` part. You may have to end up restructuring the input model.

Comment: Thanks for that, yeah i dont want to mess with the input model haha thanks ill avoid it.

Comment: :) Also btw when you set the default value from the controller you would need to set the key as string, i.e `BC.aOptions_aBadge='2'`

Comment: Thanks very much I noticed that quirk and thought to do parseInt on the `parseInt(key) as` but it didnt work, no biggie ill use string thanks very much for the foresight I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of the correct syntax. Use the keyword 'as' to mark the value you want.

```
<select
  ng-model="ref.contactTime.startTime" 
  ng-options="hour.Id as hour.Name for hour in contactHours.hours">
   <option disabled selected value="">Select time</option>
                        </select>
```

Also you might want to put your 'none' value as the default one which is done (as in the example) by placing a option in the select with a blank value.

Comment: Thanks @Arch I actually set default value in the controller so by default it loads up and selects an element :)